# Regexp in format: validation isn't stopping the right characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to regex and I'm trying to only allows letters, numbers, quotes and the following characters: !.:?!_+=, -

I have the validation below in a `guide` modal. I can name a guide just '&' if I want and it accepts it, from my understanding this validation should stop me.

```
validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
format: { with: /[a-zA-Z 1-9 0!.'":?!_+=, -]/, message: "only allows letters, numbers, quotes and !.:?!_+=, -" }
```

Not sure what is going wrong, I tested out the regex in [Rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) and it works in there.

**Edit**

After testing it, it turns out it stops '&' but lets '&11' pass. If an invalid key is with a valid key it passes. Maybe I'm using `format:` wrong or shouldn't be using `format:` for this?

Comment: The first argument to `validates` should be the name of the attribute to be validated.

Comment: @Jordan Yea sorry I just cut out the unnecessary validation information, updated it.

Comment: your regex seems to be the problem `/^[a-zA-Z 1-9 0!.'":?!_+=, -]+$/` try this instead

Comment: That gives this error `The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?`

Comment: Hmmm interesting. Was just about to do a test for it

Comment: Turns out it stops '&' but allows '&11' so if an invalid key is with valid keys it lets it through. I though `format:` stopped this type of stuff?

Comment: What if you try with `/\A[a-zA-Z0-9 !.'":?!_+=,-]+\z/` ?

Comment: Works! thanks :) Post it as an answer and ill give it to you if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified a bit your regex, added proper starting/ending line markers and added a `+` at the end to match if there is one or more char in the input. Here's what it looks like:

```
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9 !.'":?!_+=,-]+\z/
```

---

If you want to have a cleaner one:

```
/\A[\w !.'":?!_+=,-]+\z/
```

Since `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9]`